# Can I re-join a mission in progress?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

While in the middle of playing a mission, for some reason I was disconnected from Xbox Live for a brief second, so I was brought back to the story mode version.

Is there a way to re-join a mission that is already in progress? I should note that I was doing this mission solo, so it would probably be impossible to re-join. But in the instance of playing with friends, would that mission continue without me and let me get back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you can't join back.**

Also, unfortunately when you drop from a mission, if the player amount goes less than the required people for that mission (on heists, this is 2 on first, and 4 on the others), it gets cancelled for your teammates too.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a dedicated option to do so, and if You do join, GTA would place you in 'spectator mode'. So technically, no. You are not able to re-join.